# extracted data not storing in scrapy items

Tags: python, excel, selenium, scrapy, xlsxwriter

I've working on a project where I'm building a screen scraper in python using scrapy and selenium, and then take the output of the screen scraper and write it to a excel file using xlsxwriter. However, it seems like my scrapy items always remain empty. I'm not sure what's happening at this point so any help is appreciated. Just to note, theres a few urls, directories, and some other sensitive info from the script before posting here. So some of the links and directories might look weird.

Screenshot of excel output:
[Screen Scraper File Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6PHLO.png)

**Spider:**

```
import os
import time
from datetime import date
from ScreenScraper.items import *
from scrapy import *
from scrapy.http import FormRequest
from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from xlsxwriter import *


class CquentiaSpider(Spider):

    name = 'cquentia'
    allowed_domains = ['linktotable.com']          
    start_urls = ['www.linktotable.com/login'] #had to strip directories ,urls, usernames, and passwords from script.
    login_user = 'Example'
    login_pass = 'Example'
    accnt_ID_1 = 'Example'
    phantomjspath = r'C:\Users\[User]\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\ScreenScraper\Scraper\selenium\webdriver\phantomjs\bin\phantomjs.exe'

    def __init__(self, name = None, **kwargs):
        self.browser = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path=self.phantomjspath)
        return super(CquentiaSpider, self).__init__(name, **kwargs)

    def parse(self, response):        
        self.browser.get(response.url)

        username = self.browser.find_element_by_name('username')
        password = self.browser.find_element_by_name('password')
        login = self.browser.find_element_by_name('submit')

        username.send_keys(self.login_user)
        password.send_keys(self.login_pass)
        login.click()
        time.sleep(1.5)

        self.browser.get('www.linktotable.com/search')

        accnt_id = self.browser.find_element_by_name('accnId')
        search = self.browser.find_element_by_name('accnSrch')

        accnt_id.send_keys(self.accnt_ID_1)
        search.click()
        time.sleep(1.5)

        select = Selector(text=self.browser.page_source)
        get_table_count = count()
        get_table_count['row_count'] = select.xpath('//*[@id="otTable"]/thead/tr/td[1]/text()').extract() [0]
        count_final = int(get_table_count['row_count']) + 1
        patient = cquentiaPatientItems()
        patient['Pt_First_Name'] = select.xpath('//*[@id="ptFNm"]/text()').extract()
        patient['Pt_Last_Name'] = select.xpath('//*[@id="ptLNm"]/text()').extract() 
        patient['Client_ID_Name'] = select.xpath('//*[@id="clnNm"]/text()').extract()
        patient['DOS'] = select.xpath('//*[@id="dos"]/text()').extract()
        patient_First_Name = str(patient['Pt_First_Name'])
        patient_Last_Name = str(patient['Pt_Last_Name'])
        patient_Client_ID = str(patient['Client_ID_Name'])
        patient_DOS = str(patient['DOS'])
        header_layout = ['First Name:', 'Last Name:', 'Client Name:', 'DOS:']
        header_data = [patient_First_Name, patient_Last_Name, patient_Client_ID, patient_DOS]
        table_header_layout = ['Test ID', 'Name', 'Mod 1', 'Mod 2', 'Mod 3', 'Mod 4', 'Proc Code', 'Name','Units Billed $', 'Billed $', 'Gross $', 'Expect $', 'Price Method', 'Payor ID', 'POS', 'Rendering Phys']
        workbook = Workbook('%s_spider.xlsx' % (self.name))
        worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
        row = 0
        col = 0

        for value in header_layout:
            worksheet.write(row, 0, value)

            row = 1 + row

        row = 0

        for value in header_data:
            worksheet.write(row, 1, value)

            row = 1 + row


        row = 6

        for value in table_header_layout:
             worksheet.write(row, col, value)

             col = 1 + col

        col = 0
        row = 7

        for number in range(0, count_final):            

            table = Table()
            table['Test_ID'] = select.xpath('//*[@id="otTable"]/tbody/tr[%s]/td[2]/text()' % (number)).extract()
            table['Name_1'] = select.xpath('//*[@id="otTable"]/tbody/tr[%s]/td[3]/text()' % (number)).extract()
            table['Name_2'] = select.xpath('//*[@id="otTable"]/tbody/tr[%s]/td[9]/text()' % (number)).extract() 
            table['Mod_1'] = select.xpath('//*[@id="otTable"]/tbody/tr[%s]/td[4]/text()' % (number)).extract() 
            table['Mod_2'] = select.xpath('//*[@id="otTable"]/tbody/tr[%s]/td[5]/text()' % (number)).extract()
            table['Mod_3'] = select.xpath('//*[@id="otTable"]/tbody/tr[%s]/td[6]/text()' % (number)).extract() 
            table['Mod_4'] = select.xpath('//*[@id="otTable"]/tbody/tr[%s]/td[7]/text()' % (number)).extract() 
            table['Proc_Code'] = select.xpath('//*[@id="otTable"]/tbody/tr[%s]/td[8]/text()' % (number)).extract() 
            table['Units_Billed'] = select.xpath('//*[@id="otTable"]/tbody/tr[%s]/td[10]/text()' % (number)).extract()
            table['Billed'] = select.xpath('//*[@id="otTable"]/tbody/tr[%s]/td[11]/text()' % (number)).extract()
            table['Gross'] = select.xpath('//*[@id="otTable"]/tbody/tr[%s]/td[12]/text()' % (number)).extract()
            table['Expect'] = select.xpath('//*[@id="otTable"]/tbody/tr[%s]/td[13]/text()' % (number)).extract()
            table['Price_Method'] = select.xpath('//*[@id="otTable"]/tbody/tr[%s]/td[15]/text()' % (number)).extract()
            table['Payor_ID'] = select.xpath('//*[@id="otTable"]/tbody/tr[%s]/td[16]/text()' % (number)).extract()
            table['POS'] = select.xpath('//*[@id="otTable"]/tbody/tr[%s]/td[22]/text()' % (number)).extract()
            table['Rendering_Phys'] = select.xpath('//*[@id="otTable"]/tbody/tr[%s]/td[23]/text()' % (number)).extract()
            table_Test_ID = str(table['Test_ID'])
            table_Name_1 = str(table['Name_1'])
            table_Name_2 = str(table['Name_2'])
            table_Mod_1 = str(table['Mod_1'])
            table_Mod_2 = str(table['Mod_2'])
            table_Mod_3 = str(table['Mod_3'])
            table_Mod_4 = str(table['Mod_4'])
            table_Proc_Code = str(table['Proc_Code'])
            table_Units_Billed = str(table['Units_Billed'])
            table_Billed = str(table['Billed'])
            table_Gross = str(table['Gross'])
            table_Expect = str(table['Expect'])
            table_Price_Method = str(table['Price_Method'])
            table_Payor_ID = str(table['Payor_ID'])
            table_POS = str(table['POS'])
            table_Rendering_Phys = str(table['Rendering_Phys'])
            table_data = [table_Test_ID, table_Name_1, table_Mod_1, table_Mod_2, table_Mod_3, table_Mod_4, table_Proc_Code, table_Name_2, table_Units_Billed, table_Billed, table_Gross, table_Expect, table_Price_Method, table_Payor_ID, table_POS, table_Rendering_Phys]

            for text in table_data:
                worksheet.write(row, col, text)

                 col = 1 + col

            row = 1 + row
            col = 0

  workbook.close()
```

**Items:**

```
from scrapy import *

class count(Item):
    row_count = Field()

class Table(Item):
    Test_ID = Field(serializer=str)
    Name_1 = Field(serializer=str)
    Name_2 = Field(serializer=str)
    Mod_1 = Field(serializer=str)
    Mod_2 = Field(serializer=str)
    Mod_3 = Field(serializer=str)
    Mod_4 = Field(serializer=str)
    Proc_Code = Field(serializer=int)
    Units_Billed = Field(serializer=str)
    Billed = Field(serializer=str)
    Gross = Field(serializer=str)
    Expect = Field(serializer=str)
    Price_Method = Field(serializer=str)
    Payor_ID = Field(serializer=str)
    POS = Field(serializer=str)
    Rendering_Phys = Field(serializer=str)

 class cquentiaPatientItems(Item):
    Pt_First_Name = Field(serializer=str)
    Pt_Last_Name = Field(serializer=str)
    Client_ID_Name = Field(serializer=str)
    DOS = Field()
```

Comment: Have you tried removing `tbody` from the xpath ?

Comment: Yeah. Doesn't work. Plus there's a header in the table I'm scraping so I need it.

Comment: Have you added logs to check if the data is there before writing to CSV? (insert some `self.logger.debug("loop iteration: data: %r" % data)` here and there). I suggest you yield Items, to .json perhaps, and see what you get. Also, your current code is quite hard to read. Instead of counting rows and them looping on `range(0, count)`, it's usually cleaner to loop on the elements themselves, like `for row  in select.xpath('//*[@id="otTable"]/tbody/tr'):` and then using relative XPath, like `table['Test_ID'] = row.xpath('./td[2]/text()').extract_first()`

Comment: Just curious, but do you have this example using css selector paths instead of xpaths?